# Recover directories just deleted in Nautilus

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ntfs, data-recovery

In Nautilus, I accidentally delete several directories on a partition (unfortunately, I deleted them in a way such that they don't remain in Trash). I haven't write any new data to that partition yet. I wonder what ways are the best to recover them? Solutions in Ubuntu will be preferred although not the only ones. Thanks!

The partition is NTFS, shared between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before.  Not a nice situation to be in.  Your files are PROBABLY still there provided you didn't continue to write files on your system.  When a file deletes, small made is made on the harddisk to remove it. There are applications out there to help undelete these files.

http://www.winundelete.com/?rid=google&kid=wu0410

Hope this helps.  I had to do this once.  Not a bad until to keep on your system.  This isn't the only tool that can buy to do this.  There are many others.  I think this tool should do it.  Read it over...